# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)= 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)= 1
$$

Comment: See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html

Comment: comparison test

Comment: Probably the reason for the down-votes and the votes to close is that this is phrased too much like a homework problem and doesn't explain specifically what difficulties you had with it.  They ought to explain that here instead of just down-voting and voting to close. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If you try adding up the first six terms, I predict you will see a pattern, and that will answer your question.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

We have the partial sum $S_N$

$$\begin{align}
S_N&=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\\\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}\right)\\\\
&=1-\frac{1}{N+2}
\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)=\lim_{N\to \infty}S_N=1$$

Comment: In view of the terseness of the question, I think answers like the one I posted here are more appropriate. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Those answers are more appropriate than what?

Comment: I think a more detailed answer is more appropriate if the question is more detailed.  Also, my answer is of a sort that those who don't really understand algebra will understand. A stock answer to that is that students should work on strengthening their understanding of algebra, and in most cases I disagree with that, except when algebra is what the question is about. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I appreciate your comment.  But I don't see a significant difference in our posted answers.  Perhaps mine is a bit more complete.

Comment: I've tutored hundreds of students in algebra on a one-to-one basis over several decades.  Maybe that's why I'm more sensitive to this difference than most people are.

Comment: @Michael Hardy I haven't tutored students, but I can see that the difference is enormous.

Comment: @Servaes Enormous? That is an interesting comment.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 3):

If you try adding up the first six terms, I predict you will see a pattern, and that will answer your question.
$$
\overbrace{1 - \frac 1 2}^{n=0} + \overbrace{\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 3}^{n=1} + \overbrace{\frac 13-\frac14}^{n=3} + \overbrace{\frac 14 - \frac 1 5}^{n=4}
$$
You see lots of cancelations.

Comment: does it diverges to 1